# Java draw line on a JPanel via method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

I'd like to find a way how to define a method which when called will draw a line on a JPanel. I was not able how to figure this out when overriding PaintComponent.
It should look like this...

```
class MyCanvas extends JPanel {
    My Canvas () {
    ...
    }
    public void drawLineOnCanvas(x1, y1, x2, y1) {
    ...code which draws a line
    }
}
```

Comment: Call the method from paintComponent, you will need to pass the Graphics context from paintComponent to this method

Answer (score 1):

Call the method from `paintComponent`, you will need to pass the `Graphics` context from `paintComponent` to this method

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawLine(g, fromX, fromY, toX, toY);
}

public void drawLineOnCanvas(Graphics g, x1, y1, x2, y1) {
...code which draws a line
}
```